# Скриншот формы

Tags: delphi

Подскажите код: как сделать скриншот формы при помощи BitMap? Если форму закрыло или прикрыло другое приложение, то скриншот всё равно должен создаваться по координатам формы и она также будет прикрыта (закрыта)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Попробуйте так:**

```
...
var bmp:TbitMap;
Begin
bmp:=tbitmap.Create;
bmp.Width:=form1.Width-15;
bmp.Height:=form1.Height-30;
BitBlt(bmp.Canvas.Handle,0,0,form1.Width,form1.Height,getdc(form1.handle),0,0,SRCCOPY);
image2.Picture.Assign(bmp);
...
```

Comment: Хороший способ, но он не подходит мне (TransparentColor становится непрозрачным). Можно как-нибудь сделать скриншот экрана и обрезать его?

Comment: Исправил код. Теперь работает.

Comment: Не, не. У меня просто TransparentColor не работает таким образом, можно это как-то исправить?

Comment: bmp.transparent:=true;
    bmp.transparentcolor:=clwhite;

так?

Comment: Да уж, какая нелепая ошибка была)
Спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста =)